# extract date from string in Scala efficiently

Tags: java, scala, scala-collections, scalatest

I want to extract the date (e.g. `2015-01-01`) from multiple strings that have the form in Scala:

```
val s = "basedir/somedir/tmp/BLAH/2015-01-01.txt"
```

I know I can do basic string split-trim-strip operations to achieve that, but is there a more cleaner way to do it in Scala? Can I use some nice regex "hidden features" that Scala offers to do this?

I tried this without much success:

```
val s = "basedir/somedir/tmp/BLAH/2015-01-01.txt"
val regex = "(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+).txt"
val regex(year, month, date) = s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Pattern matching using regex extractor

```
val regex = ".*/(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}).txt".r //remove / after .* if you think its not needed.

str match {
  case regex(date) => Some(date)
  case _ => None
}
```

Use above code instead of below because below one will cause match error at runtime.

```
val regex(a) = "basedir/somedir/tmp/BLAH/2015-01-01.txt"
```

Instead of `.*` in front of the regex. You can use `unanchored`.

```
val regex = "(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}).txt".r.unanchored
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala>  val regex = "(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}).txt".r.unanchored
regex: scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex = (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).txt

scala> val regex(a) = "basedir/somedir/tmp/BLAH/2015-01-01.txt"
a: String = 2015-01-01
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val regex = ".*/(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}).txt".r
regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = .*/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).txt

scala> val regex(a) = "basedir/somedir/tmp/BLAH/2015-01-01.txt"
a: String = 2015-01-01
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val str = "basedir/somedir/tmp/BLAH/2015-01-01.txt"
str: String = basedir/somedir/tmp/BLAH/2015-01-01.txt

scala>  val regex = ".*/(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}).txt".r
regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = .*/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).txt

scala>
     |     str match {
     |       case regex(date) => Some(date)
     |       case _ => None
     |     }
res21: Option[String] = Some(2015-01-01)
```

**If you want to match directory as well then**

```
scala val regex = ".*/(.*)/(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}).txt".r
regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = .*/(.*)/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).txt

scala> val s = "basedir/somedir/tmp/BLAH/2015-01-01.txt"
s: String = "basedir/somedir/tmp/BLAH/2015-01-01.txt"

scala> val regex(dir, date) = s
dir: String = "BLAH"
date: String = "2015-01-01"
```

Comment: what if I also want to extract the directory in which the "YYYY-MM-dd.txt" file is in? So, let's say I want to extract ("BLAH", ''2015-01-01") as a tuple instead of just "2015-01-01"? Thanks.

Comment: @Darth.Vader edited the answer and added want you want at the end. Have a look

Comment: @Darth.Vader basically change the regex to incorporate dir also

Comment: I am running this parser on a list of directories with txt files. How can I put the results in a hashmap with DIRECTORY_NAME as key and FILE_NAME as value?

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I was condemned to parse some log files with three or four different time representations on each line.

I recommend minimal regex and maximal typed things.

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_101).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val s = "basedir/somedir/tmp/BLAH/2015-01-01.txt"
s: String = basedir/somedir/tmp/BLAH/2015-01-01.txt

scala> val r = raw".*/([\d-]*)\.txt".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = .*/([\d-]*)\.txt

scala> val r(date) = s
date: String = 2015-01-01

scala> import java.time._, format._, DateTimeFormatter._
import java.time._
import format._
import DateTimeFormatter._

scala> ISO_LOCAL_DATE.parse(date)
res0: java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor = {},ISO resolved to 2015-01-01

scala> Instant.from(res0)
java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain Instant from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2015-01-01 of type java.time.format.Parsed
  at java.time.Instant.from(Instant.java:378)
  ... 27 elided
Caused by: java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: InstantSeconds
  at java.time.format.Parsed.getLong(Parsed.java:203)
  at java.time.Instant.from(Instant.java:373)
  ... 27 more

scala> LocalDate.from(res0)
res2: java.time.LocalDate = 2015-01-01
```

Other variants for convenience:

```
scala> object LocalDateX { def unapply(s: String): Option[LocalDate] = util.Try(LocalDate.from(ISO_LOCAL_DATE.parse(s))).toOption }
defined object LocalDateX

scala> val r(LocalDateX(date)) = s
date: java.time.LocalDate = 2015-01-01
```

or

```
scala> implicit class RContext(val sc: StringContext) {
     | object r {
     |   def apply(args: Any*) = sc.s(args: _*)
     |   def unapplySeq(s: String) = sc.parts.mkString("(.+)").r.unapplySeq(s)
     | }}
defined class RContext

scala> val r".*/${LocalDateX(date)}.txt" = s
date: java.time.LocalDate = 2015-01-01
```

Comment: I think there are wrappers around the time libs, but I don't know if they provide convenience extractors.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in two lines.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
val date_format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
date_format.format(date_format.parse("2017-10-26 09:15:54.127"))
res39: String = 2017-10-26
```